# SSAS MDX not returning data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have one cube 'Performance Measure' and querying data from the cube. My problem is, on my dimensional and fact tables I can see data for July 2014, when I run a SQL query against my database then I see the data with proper counts but when I run the MDX version of the query then it doesn't fetch any data from the cube. Below is the query I am using:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{ 
    [Measures].[Error Count] 
} ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY 
{ 
    ([Dim Contractor].[Contractor Code].[Contractor Code].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim Provider].[Provider Code].[Provider Code].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim Time].[Year].[Year].[2014] 
     * [Dim Time].[Month].[Month].[7] 
     * [Dim Time].[Day].[Day].ALLMEMBERS) 
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [PerformanceMeasureCube] 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

When I commented 'NON EMPTY' from measures and sets then I saw the MDX query returned NULL data for 'Error Count' measure.

Comment: Has this worked for some time and now suddenly there is a problem, or did it never work?

Comment: It's working now. Since I am new to SSAS, I was not aware of the fact that we need to process the cube everytime we update fact and dimension tables.

Comment: Not every time you change then, just every time you do a change that changes the structure. Purely changing names or visibility, or changing the calculation script does not need a re-processing.